# htaccess block access except certain folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Have a company site where the company has shutdown and all access to the website is blocked except specific IP's. All other requests from other IP's are redirected.

I need to allow access to a couple of specific folders to all IP's.

So the original redirect portion was simply:

```
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.45.67.89$
    RewriteRule !^news$ ./news.html [L]
```

So I added some lines to that for the directories...

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^folder1$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^folder2$
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.45.67.89$
    RewriteRule !^news$ ./news.html [L]
```

As that stands it should be implementing 'AND' where all those conditions need to be true to process the rewrite rule is my understanding. I'm lost. It's not working and I have researched a played around with variants to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here? I need folks to be able to access folder1 and folder2 from any IP. I need anyone accessing any other part of the site without a specific IP to be redirected.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished my goal with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(folder1|folder2|folder3) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.45.67.89$
RewriteRule !^news$ news.html [L]
```